# Rails: How to make select field display informations from few columns and return only one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a select field that will display few informations from my db (it will be more user friendly) and return only id of chosen record. I'm not sure if it's possible to make it the "rails way" and this is why I'm writing this question. In my code I have:

```
<%= f.select :workerid, User.where(isworker: true).pluck(:id, :last_name) %>
```

At the moment this select is displaying only ids of users (without names) and that's really annoying me. I was trying to use .collect, or .map, but it was working the same way. It would be great if someone could show me how to display multiple columns in this select.

The second thing is, if I can manage to do it, how to make it send to db only id of chosen user. I think this is possible to do in jQuery but I will be thankful if someone would tell me if I can do it in Ruby language.

Comment: do you want to to display the id with the users name like "123123-name"? If you want to that you can use map and join like `User.where(isworker: true).pluck(:id, :last_name).map{|db_fields| db_fields.join('-')}`

Comment: Thanks! It works very well. It was very fast answer. Thanks once again!